# Short url for StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, short-links

Sometimes, writing `stackoverflow.com` and hitting `Enter` on keyboard comes longer and harder. If there was a chance to enter here with shorter urls like `so.to`, `so.in` or ,stck.in`, or etc. could it be better?

Comment: In comments, you can use the [magic links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments): `[SO]` becomes [SO]. These [have been requested for posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139648/shorthand-links-in-posts-as-well-as-comments), too.

Comment: c'mon! If you are on a computer that you use often you just type <kbd>s</kbd> then hit enter and you are going to SO directly !

Comment: @HugoDozois I have a browser that is set to be cleaned everything after being closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>[s.tk/so](http://s.tk/so) redirects</del> ***used to redirect*** to Stack Overflow. There are also many [shortcuts for other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109795/what-shortened-urls-are-available-through-s-tk/109802#109802) through s.tk.

Comment: I haven't recognize it before. I'll add it to my mind. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried s.tk/so and it doesn't work. it says "link not found"

Comment: http://s.tk/so no longer works.