# Short link to other sites in the network

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

How about having a short link to other sites in the StackExchange network?

e.g.:

`[site:superuser]` displays as [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

`[site:cs]` displays as [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

`[site:area51]` displays as [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

(a better suggestion of minimal typing to link to other sites is welcome)

I often point users to other sites where questions (may) belong, but the overhead to linking to the URL is quite significant sometimes.

**Also:** It may be worth thinking about whether we'd want to use something like `[site:cs/something_goes_here]` for [CS/something_goes_here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/something_goes_here), though I don't think I'll ever use that format.

**Note:** Apologies if this already exists, has already been suggested or something similar has been declined. I'm not really sure how to phrase these things in square brackets.

**EDIT:**

I mainly want these in comments (not really a need for it otherwise as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139649/206447)), and this is, as mentioned, already covered by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/152859)

Comment: This is possible only in comments at the moment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/152859

Comment: For future reference, the agreed-upon name is "magic links". =D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's basically what I wanted, thanks. Should I delete or wait to (probably) be closed as duplicate?

Comment: Sounds like you want it in posts too, not just comments right? In such case it was already suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139648/152859). No need to delete in my opinion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Mainly comments. Mentioned that in edited.

Comment: Cheers, dupe it is then but no need to delete. People might find your post first. :)